# IOS Push Notification : Authentication Failed

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp, apns-sharp

I'm getting the same error on both projects (APNS Sharp | Push Sharp)

> Authentication failed because remote party has closed the transport
>   stream

I've tried with changing `X509Certificate` to `X509Certificate2` and `X509CertificateCollection` to `X509Certificate2Collection`. I have also tried with `.Ssl3` to `.tls` or `.Default`! i have tried various solution but my error remains the same. I am using `.pem` file as my certificate.